# add 1 to a bitset of 32 bits

Tags: c++, binary, addition, bitset

I have a bitset of 32 bit and i wish to add 1 to it using the binary method of addition. So I have a in binary format and now I want to add 1 to it in binary style, is there a default method to do it or will I have to create a function for it.

```
    #include<string.h>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<bitset>
    #include<cstlib>
    int main(){
        int a;
        cin >> hex >> a;
        bitset<32> binary(a);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::bitset` is assignable from an `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`.

It also has accessors for these types.

```
#include <bitset>

auto get() -> std::bitset<32>;
auto put(std::bitset<32>) -> void;

int main(){
    auto bs = get();
    bs = bs.to_ulong() + 1;
    put(bs);
}
```

example assembler output:

```
main:
  sub rsp, 8
  call get()
  lea edi, [rax+1]
  call put(std::bitset<32ul>)
  xor eax, eax
  add rsp, 8
  ret
```

Note that the compiler is bright enough to realise that there's no need to do any copying or conversion.

Comment: Can you give the reference of `get` and `put` function?

Comment: I just wrote them as placeholders so that the generated code would have markers that we could see

Answer (score 2):

While the answer in itself is easy, I'll contribute to some good coding style advice.

You could, given the code you show, use `std::bitset::to_ulong()` and then add, or do whatever you want before converting back.

But there are few style issues on your code, and one who could break some of the logic on future architectures.

The `int` datatype is *not* guaranteed to be 32-bit by the standard. It is guaranteed to represent the integral type the architecture you're compiling for is the most efficient with.

`uint32_t` is what you need, it is guaranteed to be 32 bit long, on all architectures.

And, `std::bitset` is not really good at it's job. It's not efficient at all for sizes greater than the `int` type, as indexing needs to be done, and not more efficient than the `int` type if it's below the size of the int type. And, by the fact that the way to do non bitwise operations with it is to cast it to `long` , it is *not* guaranteed that your addition will be faster or even the same speed as if it were with `int`.

So , for your usage of it, the most efficient type would definitly be `uint32_t`, being unsigned protecting it of some undefined behavior on signed types bitwise operations.

And, while you are at coding efficient and maintanable code, you can read this : [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)